# Custom Search API

Tags: java, jackson

When I try to use google custom search API I got the error. 
In server Google I can see my requests.

code:

```
public class Main {
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "MyWeb";

private static final String API_KEY = "00000";
private static final String engine = ("000000");


private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static Customsearch client;


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Customsearch customsearch = new Customsearch(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),null);
    try {
      Customsearch.Cse.List list = customsearch.cse().list("HERE");
        list.setKey(API_KEY);
        list.setCx(engine);
        Search results = list.execute();
        List<Result> items = results.getItems();

        for(Result result:items)
        {
            System.out.println("Title:"+result.getHtmlTitle());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.createJsonParser(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Lcom/google/api/client/json/JsonParser;
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.korney.Main.main(Main.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You have an API on the classpath do you also have an implementation? if that is not the problem post some code please...

Comment: where you user `JsonFactory` class

Answer (score 0):

As also suggested in comment by lakshman, this is almost certainly due to the lack of an implementation of a `com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory` in the construction of your `Customsearch` object, you are currently setting this to null.  Try adding an implementation of this.

there is currently some JavaDoc at http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg-history/69fdf148d5a867b841f4146132343304e73cf9c1/apis/customsearch/v1/com/google/api/services/customsearch/Customsearch.html for the Customsearch object which may help you.